# ratio of tangent to the ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, parametric

The tangent at point $P = ( a \cos \phi, b \sin \phi)$ on the ellipse

$\frac{x^2} {a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

meets the $x$ and $y$ axes at the points $X$ and $Y$, respectively.

Find in terms of $\phi$ the ratio $\frac{|PX|}{|YP|}$

Comment: When you say $P(a\cos(\phi),b\sin(\phi)$ do you mean  point $P$ equal to $a\cos(\phi),b\sin(\phi)$? And then does $PX$, $PY$ mean the $x$ and $y$ coordinate of $P$?

Comment: yes, those are the x and y coordinates of point P. PX is the line between the point P and X and PY is the line between the point P and Y.

Comment: How exactly are you unsure of how to put them in a ratio? You write down the value of $|PX|$, underline it, and under the line you write the value of $|PY|$.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line at $P$ has equation
$$
\frac{x}{a}\cos\phi + \frac{y}{b}\sin\phi = 1 
$$
Substituting $y=0$, we find that the point $X$ has coordinates $\left(\tfrac{a}{\cos\phi}, 0 \right)$.

Similarly, $Y$ has coordinates $\left(0, \tfrac{b}{\sin\phi}\right)$.

Now just figure out the distances $PX$ and $PY$, and divide to get the desired ratio.